# AngularJS ng-click on small resolutions only

Tags: angularjs

I have a table

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Some</td>
      <td>Some</td>
      <td>Some</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="btn">Go Btn</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

On small devices I want to hide button and make link on all  tag.

So I need something like

```
<table>
   <tr ng-click="if(window.width()<480) window.location.href=url.html">
      ...
   </tr>
</table>
```

I need to implement this case for a lot of tables. So can I do this logic somewhere in ng-click derictive? Maybe I need to extend it or create new one?

Just please recomend me good solution with Angular Way.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can do it **in your controller** but you need to use `$window` service :

```
app.controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", "$window", function($scope, $window){
    $scope.myFunction = function(){
        if($window.document.body.clientWidth < 480){
            // ...
        }
    };
}]);

ng-click="myFunction()"
```

Or create a **custom directive**.

Or simply use **CSS `@media`** width check to hide this element and show anoter without ng-click.

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Css is good if u want a directive solution try this

```
<div ng-style="showbtnornot()" buttondirective>
```

THis would be the directive this is not 100% accurate but it should give you the idea

```
.directive('buttondirective', function (Ls, window) {
      return function (scope, element, attr, window) {
          scope.showbtnornot= function () {
             if(window.innerWidth < 400){
            return {
                'display': 'none',

            };
        } else {

            return {
                'display': 'block',

            };
        }
    }
}
})
```